# Linux screen open session and change directory

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have a question regarding the 'screen' session in Linux.

I've written a simple shell script which is supposed to open a screen session attach to it and change the directory "cd 1", where '1' is existing sub-directory in the directory from which I am running the script.
So here is what I have so far:

```
screen -d -m -S mysession
screen -S mysession -p 0 -X cd 1
```

the script, so far, only opens one screen session but when I attach to the screen I can see that it has not changed the directory.

Any idea why it won't change the directory?

Answer (score 1):

The following does the trick (it currently does come with an ugly side-effect of printing the command it just performed, though)

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -dmS mysession sh
screen -S mysession -p 0 -X stuff "cd /some/path/
"
```

Tested on OSX 10.9.5 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Still doesn't work! I am on Debian but I doubt that's the reason.
When I run the script and when I attach to the screen it is still in my home directory and not /home/1/

Comment: Have you tried absolute path? /home/abedin/1/ (assuming your user is abedin). Also, I doubt you have a directory named '1' under /home/, where only user directories (usually) should be.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but the absolute path to the directory '1' is "/home/abedin/test/1". I am running my script from "/home/abedin/test" and when I attach to the screen, I am still in "/home/abedin/test". And yes, I tried with the absolute path but still the same.

Comment: In OSX I have Bash 3.2.53 and Screen 4.00.03. Ubuntu: Bash 4.2.25 and Screen 4.00.03jw4, if that's to any help. Working in both OSX and Ubuntu.